# MySQL AUTOCOMMIT status while using BEGIN and START TRANSACTION

Tags: mysql, transactions, autocommit

I need to use a transaction in my project on MySQL. But I'm not sure if I have to use `mysql_query("SET AUTOCOMMIT=0");` or not.
I know I have 2 options:

1. BEGIN
2. START TRANSACTION

Also I have heard that one of the both items does not need using `AUTOCOMMIT = 0`.
Please help me to know when I have to use `AUTOCOMMIT = 0` actually, With `BEGIN` or with `START TRANSACTION`?

Thank you.

Comment: @Random I have to do it unfortunately. I have a project with many lines of codes written in this way and it's so hard to change them.

Comment: But you have to face this hard work to provide security to your users

Comment: @Random this was not my question, I just need to know basics about MySQL Transactions. Can you give me your answer about my question please?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As explained in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/commit.html):

> By default, MySQL runs with [autocommit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/glossary.html#glos_autocommit) mode enabled. This means that as soon as you execute a statement that updates (modifies) a table, MySQL stores the update on disk to make it permanent. The change cannot be rolled back.
>
> To disable autocommit mode implicitly for a single series of statements, use the `START TRANSACTION` statement:
>
> ```
> START TRANSACTION;
> SELECT @A:=SUM(salary) FROM table1 WHERE type=1;
> UPDATE table2 SET summary=@A WHERE type=1;
> COMMIT;
> ```
>
> With `START TRANSACTION`, autocommit remains disabled until you end the transaction with `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`. The autocommit mode then reverts to its previous state.

The manual goes on to say:

> To disable autocommit mode explicitly, use the following statement:
>
> ```
> SET autocommit=0;
> ```
>
> After disabling autocommit mode by setting the [`autocommit`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_autocommit) variable to zero, changes to transaction-safe tables (such as those for [`InnoDB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) or [`NDBCLUSTER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-cluster.html)) are not made permanent immediately. You must use `COMMIT` to store your changes to disk or `ROLLBACK` to ignore the changes.
>
> [`autocommit`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_autocommit) is a session variable and must be set for each session. To disable autocommit mode for each new connection, see the description of the [`autocommit`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_autocommit) system variable at [Section 5.1.3, “Server System Variables”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html).
>
> `BEGIN` and `BEGIN WORK` are supported as aliases of `START TRANSACTION` for initiating a transaction. `START TRANSACTION` is standard SQL syntax and is the recommended way to start an ad-hoc transaction.

Comment: Thank you eggyal. I'd seen this article in MySQL official website. But I saw some articles that had said when we use `BEGIN`, we don't need to set `AUTOCOMMIT = 0`, but when we use `START TRANSACTION` we must do it. Regarding to what I said, and to this article, what is your idea ?

Comment: @eggyal You mean you **don't** need to disable autocommit when using `START TRANSACTION` and/or `BEGIN`? It will be automatically disabled?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: `SET autocommit=0`, `START TRANSACTION` and `BEGIN` are all equivalent—except for the state in which MySQL will be when the transaction *ends* (because it is committed or rolled back): if you have `autocommit=0`, then MySQL will automatically commence a new transaction (as though `START TRANSACTION` or `BEGIN` had been issued again); whereas if you have `autocommit=1` (because one of the other commands was issued) then MySQL will return to automatically committing every statement, and another `START TRANSACTION` or `BEGIN` statement will be required to commence a new transaction

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: So the answer to your question is "yes, one doesn't need to disable autocommit when using `START TRANSACTION` or `BEGIN`".

Comment: That's what the manual says, but that's not the behavior I'm getting in my testing. I have to set autocommit back to false after  the transaction, or else my other non-transaction queries don't execute. I'm using PHP 5.6.28 , mysql 5.1.73, and the function `mysqli_autocommit`

Answer (score 1):

There is a small difference between Start Transaction and SET AUTOCOMMIT=0.
If START TRANSACTION appears at the beginning of session and AUTOCOMMIT is set 1 (Mysql begins with AUTOCOMMIT enabled) after ROLLBACK, Autocommit is set silently to 1 again
If I put SET AUTOCOMMIT=0, instead of START TRANSACTION, evidently a ROLLBACK let AUTOCOMMIT disabled

Comment: Please consider re-formatting the text.